# Pandoc not convert file doc has math to file latex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, latex, pandoc

Hello everyone I have a problem that is difficult to answer.

I have the function to convert the doc file with the math formula to a .tex (latex) file. But when converting to .tex file, the mathematical formula in .doc file, .docx file error

- file doc

[image]

- File convert latex

[image]

Can you help me fix it? Thank you!